# Calculate percentage of overlap in TimeSpans

Tags: c#, datetime, overlap, timespan

```
BREAK
24.1.2018 13.10 - 24.1.2018 13.30
24.1.2018 19.00 - 26.1.2018 15.00

AVAILABILITY    
24.1 13.00-14.00 = 66.67%
25.1 13.00-14.00 = 0%;
```

I see that there are breaks as the example above.
I would like to check how many percentage this break covers of 2 given datetime. For example  13.00-14.00 for 24.1 and 25.1... As eye tells 25) 13-14, availability is 0... and 24.1 13.00-14.00 its 66.67%.

How can i with help of a library or code calculate  programmatically  this percentage?

> CalcPercentage(Breakstart, breakend, availability start,availability
>   start) that would return for example 66,67

Comment: So, where is your code ?

Comment: I have no idea where to start, easiest would be if there is already a library for this.

Comment: The place to start is writing out a formula as if you were going to do it on paper. Determine what inputs you need, and make those arguments to a method. Then implement your formula inside that method: given the necessary input, calculate and return the result. Then come back here if you get stuck!! :)

Comment: Its not as easy. You will need an algorithm.

Comment: Note that subtracting a DateTime frim another returns the elapsed time between them.

Comment: Yes, but if you have overlapping break periods, you might subtract parts of periods twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we want to subtract break periods from the total length of the considered availability period, we must ensure that the break periods do not overlap each other, otherwise we might subtract a period or a part of it twice.

First, we need a type representing periods:

```
public class Period
{
    public Period(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        Start = start;
        End = end;
    }

    public DateTime Start { get; }
    public DateTime End { get; }
    public TimeSpan Duration => End - Start;

    public Period Intersect(Period other)
    {
        long start = Math.Max(Start.Ticks, other.Start.Ticks);
        long end = Math.Min(End.Ticks, other.End.Ticks);
        if (start > end) { // Periods not overlapping or touching.
            return null;
        }
        return new Period(new DateTime(start), new DateTime(end));
    }

    public Period Union(Period other)
    {
        if (other.Start > End || other.End < Start) { // Periods not overlapping or touching.
            return null;
        }
        return new Period(
            new DateTime(Math.Min(Start.Ticks, other.Start.Ticks)),
            new DateTime(Math.Max(End.Ticks, other.End.Ticks))
        );
    }
}
```

It also contains methods for intersection (= overlapping part) and union of periods.

Replace overlapping or touching periods by single period:

```
private List<Period> CondensePeriods(IEnumerable<Period> periods)
{
    List<Period> tmp = periods.ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < tmp.Count; i++) {
        Period first = tmp[i]; // Compare this period to all following ones.
        // Loop in reverse order because we are removing entries.
        for (int j = tmp.Count - 1; j > i; j--) {
            Period condensed = first.Union(tmp[j]);
            if (condensed != null) { // Periods overlap or are touching.
                // Replace first period with a condensed period.
                tmp[i] = condensed;

                // Remove the other period.
                tmp.RemoveAt(j);
            }
        }
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

Note that `CondensePeriods` has an O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity and is therefore not optimized for many break periods.

Finally we can calculate the availability like this:

```
public double AvailabilityPercentage(IEnumerable<Period> breaks, Period period)
{
    // First replace overlapping or touching break periods by single period.
    breaks = CondensePeriods(breaks);

    // Now remove these non-overlapping breaks from the tested period.
    long totalPeriodDuration = period.Duration.Ticks;
    long available = totalPeriodDuration;
    foreach (Period brk in breaks) {
        // Take part of break that lies within the tested period.
        var intersection = brk.Intersect(period);
        if (intersection != null) { // Break is not outside of period.
            available -= intersection.Duration.Ticks;
        }
    }

    return 100.0 * available / totalPeriodDuration;
}
```

(tested)

If you are sure that your break periods never overlap, you can drop `breaks = CondensePeriods(breaks);`.

Comment: Great answer. I focused too much on the OP's method signature, but you answered the question as a whole. I can see `Period` having a `public static List<Period> CondensePeriods(List<Period> periods)` method that contains the initial code in your `AvailabilityPercentage` method.

Comment: Yes, my code can be refactored. I extracted methods for intersection and union into `Period`. I think `Period` should only contain stuff related to single periods and not to collections of periods; however, the condensing part can be extracted to a separate method. It makes the code more readable. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Given your sample method signature, you could do something like this:

```
public static double CalcPercentage(DateTime breakStart, DateTime breakEnd, 
    DateTime availStart, DateTime availEnd)
{
    // "fail or return fast" argument checks
    if (breakStart >= breakEnd || availStart >= availEnd) return 0;
    if (breakStart > availEnd || breakEnd < availStart) return 100;
    if (breakStart < availStart && breakEnd > availEnd) return 0;

    // Calc total minutes available, actual minutes available, and the percentage
    var totalAvailMin = (availEnd - availStart).TotalMinutes;
    var actualAvailMin = 0.0;
    if (availStart < breakStart) actualAvailMin += (breakStart - availStart).TotalMinutes;
    if (availEnd > breakEnd) actualAvailMin += (availEnd - breakEnd).TotalMinutes;
    var percentage = actualAvailMin / totalAvailMin * 100;

    return percentage;
}
```

The usage of this method, using your sample data, might look like:

```
static void Main()
{
    var breakStart = new DateTime(2018, 1, 24, 13, 10, 0);
    var breakEnd = new DateTime(2018, 1, 24, 13, 30, 0);
    var availStart = new DateTime(2018, 1, 24, 13, 00, 0);
    var availEnd = new DateTime(2018, 1, 24, 14, 00, 0);
    var availPercent = CalcPercentage(breakStart, breakEnd, availStart, availEnd);

    Console.WriteLine($"{availPercent:0.00}%");

    Console.Write("\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]